# Array-backed heap structures for Java

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

I'm looking for heap structures for priority queues that can be implemented using `Object[]` arrays **instead** of `Node` objects.

Binary heaps of course work well, and so do n-ary heaps. Java's `java.util.PriorityQueue` is a binary heap, using an `Object[]` array as storage.

There are plenty of other heaps, such as Fibonacci heaps for example, but as far as I can tell, these need to be implemented using nodes. And from my benchmarks I have the impression that the overhead paid by managing all these node objects comes at a cost that may well eat up all benefits gained. I find it very hard to implement a heap that can comete with the simple array-backed binary heap.

So I'm currently looking for advanced heap / priority queue structures that also do not have the overhead of using `Node` objects. Because I want it to be fast in reality, not just better in complexity theory... and there is much more happening in reality: for example the CPU has L1, L2 and L3 caches etc. that do affect performance.

My question also focuses on **Java** for the very reason that I have little influence on memory management here, and there are no `struct`s as in C. A lot of heaps that work well when implemented in C become costly in Java because of the memory management overhead and garbage collection costs.

Answer (score 3):

Several uncommon heap structures can be implemented this way.  For example, [the Leonardo Heap used in Dijkstra's smoothsort algorithm](http://keithschwarz.com/smoothsort/) is typically implemented as an array augmented with two machine words.  Like a binary heap, the array representation is an array representation of a specific tree structure (or rather, a forest, since it's a collection of trees).

The [poplar heap structure](http://iwi.eldoc.ub.rug.nl/FILES/root/1991/InfProcLettBron/1991InfProcLettBron.pdf) was introduced as a slightly less efficient theoretically but more efficient practically heap structure with the same basic idea - the data is represented as an array with some extra small state information, and is a compressed representation of a forest structure.

A more canonical array-based heap is a [d-ary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap), which is a natural generalization of the binary heap to have d children instead of two.

As a very silly example, a sorted array can be used as a priority queue, though it's very inefficient.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I will look at poplar and leonardo heaps. I already have toyed with n-ary heaps, and 4-ary heaps for example seem to be a bit faster most of the time.

Comment: Can you point me to any implementations of these? It seem everybody only uses binary heaps. Since C++ has powerful optimized allocators, Boost also comes with a Fibonacci heap. But neither for poplar nor leonardo heap I could find any real implementation yet; not to mention a benchmarked one.